# How to delete the last character from a TextBox?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a copy of MS Windows Calculator - just to exercise the knowledge I have acquired in the course I'm doing - and I'm having problems to write the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key, but I have no idea about how to delete the last character on `TxtResult.Text` (Text Box). So, can some one teach me how to do that?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ZigndSuperCalc
{
    public partial class FrmZigndSC : Form
    {
        Int64 aux, result;
        Int16 cont = 0;
        bool sucess;
        public FrmZigndSC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnSoma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sucess = Int64.TryParse(TxtInput.Text, out aux);
            result += aux;
            TxtInput.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
            TxtInput.Focus();
        }

        private void BtnCE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TxtInput.Text = "0";
        }

        private void BtnC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            result = 0;
            TxtInput.Text = "0";
        }

        private void BtnBackspace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // write here a method to delete the last character from 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show what code you've written so far.

Comment: In my case, the substring based implementations are undesirable, because they cause flicker when performed in quick succession.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, @Knickerless-Noggins? I've wrote this question a long time ago, so I might be of better help now.

Comment: Instead of replacing the control's text string with a new one, I need a way to remove the last character from the existing text. Replacing the whole string causes flicker to occur when performed repeatedly in quick succession.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins It seems that for you case it would be more appropriate to handle the key that is being pressed and deny its input, here's an example: http://pastebin.com/cP6inprT

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. You should be able to remove a character from the body of text attached to the TextBox without having to clone and replace.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If we're mimicking `calc.exe`, exactly then it's probably something like:

```
string s = TxtResult.Text;

if (s.Length > 1) {
    s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1);
} else {
    s = "0";
}

TxtResult.Text = s;
```

EDIT: As requested, the `Substring` method I'm using here extracts a portion of the string and assigns it to the `Text` property of the textbox. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx

Comment: @rein could you please add on your answer an explanation about what Subtring do?

Comment: I think TxtResult.Text = s; destroys all text formatting.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
TxtResult.Text = TxtResult.Text.Substring(0, TxtResult.Text.Length - 1);`
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if (textBox1.TextLength > 0) 
{ 
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, (textBox1.TextLength - 1)); 
} 
else 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("No Number.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this method:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textbox.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        textbox.Text = textbox.Text.Remove(textbox.Text.Length - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//CLICK ON BUTTON1

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Length > 1)
            {
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
            }![enter image description here][1]
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = "0";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Button named "buttonDel" then

```
  private void buttonDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               if (sender == buttonDel)
            {
                s = textBox1.Text;

                if (s.Length > 1)
                {
                    s = s.Substring(0,s.Length - 1);
                    textBox1.Text = s;
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "0";
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me!!

```
    private void txtNumCL_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool ctrl = Int32.TryParse(txtNumCL.Text, out int outParse);
        if (!ctrl && txtNumCL.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            txtNumCL.Text = txtNumCL.Text.Substring(0, txtNumCL.Text.Length - 1);
            txtNumCL.SelectionStart = txtNumCL.Text.Length;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

```
output.Text=output.Text.Remove(output.Text.Length-1, 1);
```

Old:
You can use:

```
TxtInput.Text = TxtInput.Text.ToString().Remove(TxtInput.Text.ToString().Length-1,1);
```